# How to expand Java Classpath Wildcards from code?

Tags: java, classpath, wildcard, expand

I'd like to expand Java classpath wildcards (New on Java 6) from code. Is there some code in Java Standard Lib that I could use instead of doing it from scratch?

Example:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        method("~/myApp/build/*:~/myLib/build/lib.jar", "com.myapp.parser.ParseClassFile");
    }

    public static void method(String classpath, String classfile) {
        actionWithClassFile(javautilmethodexpand(classpath), classfile);
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some code in Java Standard Lib that I could use instead of doing it from scratch?

No. Classpath wildcard expansion is not performed by a standard library in Java, and the expansion is performed even before any classes are loaded by the JVM. It is not a standard in the first place, and is available only if the JRE implementation supports it. As far as I know, the Oracle/Sun and OpenJDK runtimes allow for classpath wildcard expansion.

Quite obviously, you'll need to roll your own implementation if you intend to do this in Java. You can look up the implementation in C (for the OpenJDK runtime) in the `wildcard.c` file located in the `jdk/src/share/bin` directory of the sources.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Implementation in wildcard.c is nice and easy to follow.

Comment: Is wildcard expansion a standard in Java 7?

Comment: No, wildcard expansion might not even become a standard. I doubt it will in the near future, for it would require specifying all arguments that a JVM process would receive from the command line.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is not.

You could probably do this fairly easily using one of the filename wildcard methods in Apache commons [`FilenameUtils`](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html), though you'd need to split the classpath, and then filter the wildcarded list to discard any files with the wrong suffix.

---

FWIW: the NIO extensions in Java 7 include support for filename wildcarding.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is wildcard expansion a standard in Java 7?

Comment: I'll check the Apache commons implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking up on URLClassLoader. You will need to subclass it.

Below here is a sample of my custom classloader.

```
/** A <code>ClassLoader</code> that locates runtime & support libraries **/
final class MyClassLoader extends URLClassLoader {
    MyClassLoader(String libStr, ClassLoader parent) throws MalformedURLException {
        this(new File(libStr), parent);
    }

    MyClassLoader(File libDir, ClassLoader parent) throws MalformedURLException {
        super(new URL[]{libDir.toURI().toURL()}, parent);
    }

    final private String[] accepted_lib_extensions = {".jar", ".zip", ".properties"};

    void addDir(File dir) throws MalformedURLException {
        FilenameFilter filenamefilter = new FilenameFilter() {
            public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                 String smallName = name.toLowerCase();
                 for (int i = 0; i < accepted_lib_extensions.length; i++) {
                     if (smallName.endsWith(accepted_lib_extensions[i])){
                         return true;
                     }
                 }
                 return false;
            }
        };
        File[] jars = dir.listFiles(filenamefilter);
        if (jars == null) return;
        for (int i = jars.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (jars[i].isFile()) {
                final URL url = jars[i].toURI().toURL();

                // This is key in adding your own classpath to JRE
                addURL(url);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I tried and I couldn't manage something at all. Preferred a more string-related implementation.